# How to get image from notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

How to get an image from notification? I'm using NotificationListenerService.

I found the way to get a small icon and large icon. but I don't know how to get an image.
(ex. Whenever someone sent me the message text with image)

I tried 
Bitmap temp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
However "temp" is null

Help me please!

Comment: Can you please post the code that you use to create the notification object? I mean by using Notification.Builder class etc?

Comment: @Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Notification notification = sbn.getNotification();
        Bundle extras = notification.extras;

        if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {
            Bitmap temp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
        }
}

this is my code.

Comment: I am guessing you are using Firebase. If yes, then please check out this [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/205)